# Algorithm that can divide all graph nodes N into two fully connected sets?

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, python

For a given graph `G,` is there an *algorithm* that can divide all graph `G` nodes `N` into two sets – `A` and `B` `(N = A U B),` 
such that all nodes a<sub>i</sub> in set `A` are connected to all other nodes a<sub>j</sub> in `A,`
 and all nodes b<sub>i</sub> in set `B` are connected to all other nodes b<sub>j</sub> in `B?`

If the answer to the above is yes, is there a *polynomial time* algorithm?

**Example:**
The following graph can be divided into sets {1, 2, 3} and {4, 5, 6}.

[image: sample graph]

### Edits:

1. There can be nodes in both `A` and `B:` e.g., a node `n` may exist such that `n` belongs to `A` and `n` belongs to `B.`
2. If the division into two sets, as defined above, is not possible, the algorithm should recognise it and inform us.

Comment: You mean that all verticies in first subgraph connected only with verticies from first subgraph? So there is no edges between $A$ and $B$ ?

Comment: If it so, then you could use deep-first-search and find connected component.

Comment: No to your first question @openspace. As (N = A U B), there can be a node n in both A and B.

Comment: So there could be an intersection between A and B?

Comment: Yes, @openspace: see edit on the OP.

Comment: You are aware that this not always possible right?

Comment: Of course, @Carry. The algorithm should be able to answer that such a partition is not possible. I'll add it to the requirements.

Comment: How fast do you want it to run? Because there is an obvious $\mathcal O(2^{n-1})$ algorithm

Comment: Could you point me to that algorithm, @Carry, so I can determine if it's fast enough?

Comment: Seems the answer to my original question is the `Bron-Kerbosch algorithm.`

Comment: No, you obviously don't need the full power of Bron-Kerbosch, your problem is much simpler

Answer (score 1):

Two observations: If you can find $A$ and $B$ so that their union is all of $G$ and they both induce cliques then you can find $A$ and $B$ that are disjoint cover all of $G$ and also induce cliques.}

Now notice that $A$ and $B$ induce cliques if and only if there are no edges between vertices of $A$ and no edges between vertices of $B$ in the complement of $G$.

So your problem is equivalent to determining if $G^c$ is bipartite, and if it is, finding a partition of $G^c$. This can easily be done in $\mathcal O(n^2)$ time.

Here is some c++11 code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

const int MAX=1010; // maximum number of vertices
set <int> A[MAX];// A[i] stores all the neighbours of vertex i
int C[MAX]; // this store in which "part" we save vertex i

void impossible(){// I just use this to print when I realize its impossible
    printf("impossible\n");
    exit(0);
}

void dfs(int x){
    for(int y:A[x]){
        if(C[y]==C[x]) impossible();// this means the graph is not bipartite
        if(C[y]==0){
            if(C[x]==1) C[y]=2;
            else C[y]=1;
            dfs(y);
        }
    }
}

int main(){
    int n,m; // number of vertices and edges
    scanf("%d %d",&n,&m); // we read n and m
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
            if(i!=j) A[i].insert(j); // we want to build the complement, so we start adding every edge
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<m;i++){// we read the edges in G and erase them from G^c
        int u,v;
        scanf("%d %d",&u,&v);
        A[u].erase(v);
        A[v].erase(u);
    }
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        if(C[i]==0){// if i has not been explored yet we dfs from i
            C[i]=1;
            dfs(i);
        }
    }
    printf("The set A contains:\n");
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        if(C[i]==1) printf("%d ",i);
    }
    printf("\nThe set B contains:\n");
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        if(C[i]==2) printf("%d ",i);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```